# Overloading a params function with an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, generics, parameters

Suppose I have two functions:

```
Foo(params INotifyPropertyChanged[] items)
{
   //do stuff
}

Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   Foo(items.ToArray());
}
```

The second one allows me to call `Foo` from a generic class with the constraint `where T : INotifyPropertyChanged`, but the second resolves to itself so I get a stack overflow exception.

1. Is it possible to specify which overload I want to call when there's some ambiguity?
2. Is there another way to call a `params` function from a generic class, assuming the generic type's constraints make it a viable option for the `params` type?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass a `INotifyPropertyChanged[]`, not a `T[]`.
For example:

```
Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   Foo(items.Cast<INotifyPropertyChanged>().ToArray());
}
```

In general, however, it's better to call the `IEnumerable` version from the `params` version, like this:

```
Foo(params INotifyPropertyChanged[] items)
{
   Foo((IEnumerable<INotifyPropertyChanged>) items);
}

Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Cannot convert type 'T[]' to 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged[]'

Comment: Going with this answer because the latter option removes any possible ambiguity - the first one is more compiler trickery.

Answer (score 3):

You could try casting the input.

```
Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   Foo(items.Cast<INotifyPropertyChanged>().ToArray());
}
```

If this doesn't work, I don't have an idea, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: The code you provide selects Foo<T> overload, it is guarantee of stack overflowing.

Comment: Sorry, my wrong. I seem first function have Foo(params object[] items) signature.